# How to automatically create a new record in another object

Tags: apex, trigger, create-records

Whenever a new Account record is created, automatically a new contact record should be created.Need to use the instance of contact object and you can populate the required fields and ignore the rest.How to write a trigger to achieve this?

Comment: How would you capture the required fields for the Contact record, e.g. the Contact Name? Please explain more in the question - see the guidelines on how to ask [ask]

Comment: Please specify your requirement and have you tried to write the trigger. Please paste the code on which you get error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write a trigger that automatically create a contact when account is created](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27241/write-a-trigger-that-automatically-create-a-contact-when-account-is-created)

Comment: why don't you just use process builder to create new records. this will be more simple to implement

Comment: I am just a beginner and thought I could get a proper help here through concepts but No ! people are busy in marking the question off topic !

Answer (score 1):

try this ,

I am not clear with your requirement but this can be achieve by trigger

For Eg:

```
trigger CreateAccountContact on Account (after insert, after update){

if(Trigger.isInsert){

    List<Contact> ct = new List <Contact>();

    for(Account acc : trigger.new){

        Contact c = new Contact(LastName = acc.name,
                    AccountId=acc.id,
                    Fax=acc.Fax,
                    MailingStreet=acc.BillingStreet,
                    MailingCity=acc.BillingCity,
                    /* similarly add all fields which you want */
                    MailingState=acc.BillingState,
                    MailingPostalCode=acc.BillingPostalCode,
                    MailingCountry=acc.BillingCountry,
                    Phone=acc.Phone);

        ct.add(c);
    }
    insert ct; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks ,but no new contact record was created ...